# How to set custom tiff header tags in node js?

Tags: node.js, tiff

First of all, I know this is quite a specific request, in a non fitting language, but it must be done this way due to certain constraints:

I have a nodejs app that handles an existing tiff file. The one thing it needs to do is add a custom (non spec) header tag to it. Is there any package that would help me here? Or is the only way going deep into the tiff format by hand?